# My cat is incredibly stinky

Tags: cats

My cat gave birth about two months ago to five kittens. A couple weeks ago, I noticed this horrible odor that seemed to follow her wherever she went. At the time I thought she was just having some frequent smelly farts since we had recently put her on a diet with more protein, but the smell seems to hang around her 24/7.

Is this normal? Could this be a sign of some health condition? And is there anything that I can do about it?

Comment: cats should not smell at all so this is something you need to contact your vet about and you need to do it now,this is definetly a sign of possibly serious health problems in your cat.